# How to run a external Program and get the return-code in a Firefox-Addon

Tags: firefox, process, firefox-addon, return-value

Hy,
I'm trying to launch a external process from a mozilla firefox addon (so only js-code allowed). This is easly possible using [NSIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIProcess), but I need the return-code of the executed program. As the [NSIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIProcess) doesnt offer a possibility to get the return-code, I'm searching for a alternative possibility.

Im trying to avoid to write my own XPCom Compontent in C because this would make the plugin platform bound.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you gave mentions the attribute exitValue -- is that not what you're looking for?